# How to convert double to string with precision for total number of digits(both left and right side of the decimal)?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am looking for a way to convert double to string in c++ such that total number of digits remain to be 10 irrespective of how many are present before and after the decimal point and irrespective of the zeroes. Examples for better understanding:

0.00000000000000000000  =expected outcome> 0.0000000000

12345.00000000000000000  =expected outcome> 12345.00000

-15.123456789012 =expected outcome> -15.12345678

I couldnt find any relevant answer. For the methods like snprintf, std::setprecision with ostringstream, to_string, Boost's lexical_cast, some of the above case fails.

Example of code:

```
double num = 12345.0000000000001;

std::ostringstream streamObj2;

streamObj2 << std::fixed <<  std::setprecision(10) << num;

std::string strObj2 = streamObj2.str();

std::cout  << strObj2 << '\n';
```

The output = 12345.0000000000, which is not what I am expecting. Removing std::fixed gives output as 12345

What I require = 12345.00000

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: There's nothing called C/C++.

Comment: is this not what `std::setprecision` does? Which case fails? Please include your code in the question

Comment: std::setprecision only sets precision for digits after the decimal as per what i have searched

Comment: @Rogenwiczar no thats not what it does. Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question

Comment: I’m not aware of a particular std function that could do exactly that. I’d just do `std::setprecision` + `std::setfixed`, then trim with `std::basic_string::substr`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 `std::setprecision` by itself does not add padding `0` ; `std::setprecision` with `std::setfixed` applies only to decimal digits AFAIK

Comment: @Maliafo not saying that `std::setprecision` alone is the solution. Rather trying to make OP post their code so we can see what is actually missing

Comment: example code added. I am new here, thanks for understanding

Comment: See std::fixed and std::showpoint in combination

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments, because of which I found the answer. Using std::showpoint instead of std::fixed helped fulfill the requirement.

double num = 12345.0000000000001;

std::ostringstream streamObj2;

streamObj2 << **std::showpoint** <<  std::setprecision(10) << num;

std::string strObj2 = streamObj2.str();

std::cout  << strObj2 << '\n';

Output: 12345.00000